# Angular Factory dependency issue

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 factories: ApiService and LocationService.

In ApiService i'd like to return the endpoint from an $http call that LocationService will use.

But it seems when the controller calls LocationService, it doesn't wait for the response from ApiService. Here is some snippet of code, in ApiService when I finally get it working I will cache it so I won't need to make a server call each time to get the endpoint:

```
    services.factory("ApiService", ["$location", "$http", function ($location, $http) {
    return {
        getEndpointUrl: function () {
            var endpoint;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/site/apiendpoint'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                endpoint = response.data;
                console.log(endpoint);
                return endpoint;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.error('Error retrieving API endpoint');
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the location service, it consumes ApiService:

```
    services.factory("LocationService", ["$resource", "ApiService", function ($resource, apiService) {
    var baseUri = apiService.getEndpointUrl();
    return $resource(baseUri + '/location', {}, {
        usStates: { method: 'GET', url: baseUri + '/location/us/states' }
    });
}]);
```

When my controller tries to call LocationService.usStates the baseUri is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because your `getEndpointUrl` function is asynchronous, and it has no return value.

Since your `LocationService` uses $resource and depends on on the `baseUri`, I would suggest bootstrapping that data along with the initial page load and making it a constant like:

```
angular.module('yourModule').constant('baseUrl', window.baseUrl);
```

Then your service would inject it to create your resource:

```
   services.factory("LocationService", ["$resource", "ApiService", "baseUrl", function ($resource, apiService, baseUrl) {
       return $resource(baseUrl + '/location', {}, {
          usStates: { method: 'GET', url: baseUrl + '/location/us/states' }
       });
   }]);
```

Comment: Hi, this would be perfect but how do I set that constant dynamically the first time? As I have to get the endpoint from another endpoint, if that makes any sense, that endpoint could be different per environment.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: .NET MVC (returns the API endpoing) and another Web API 2 project (that is the endpoint). My initial idea was to set endpoint based on the url they are on (location.host()) but I am looking for something more cleaner, i have the setting in my web.config.

Comment: I suggested this approach on an older question too actually. Here's a link to it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597439/manual-bootstrap-angular-with-http-calls/37598552#37598552

Comment: This is perfect, I am just going to serialize it and use window.configuration. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `ApiService`, you're not actually returning a value from `getEndpointUrl()`. How about you return a promise from `ApiService`, and then consume that in `LocationService` in a synchronous fashion?

```
services.factory("ApiService", ["$location", "$http", function($location, $http) {
    return {
        getEndpointUrl: function() {
            var endpoint;

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/site/apiendpoint'
            });
        }
    }
}]);

services.factory("LocationService", ["$resource", "ApiService", function($resource, apiService) {
    return {
        getLocations: function() {
            return apiService.getEndpointUrl().then(function successCallback(response) {
                var baseUri = response.data;

                return $resource(baseUri + '/location', {}, {
                    usStates: { method: 'GET', url: baseUri + '/location/us/states' }
                });

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.error('Error retrieving API endpoint');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And then in your controller:

```
LocationService.getLocations().then(function(data) {
    $scope.statesResult = data.result.states;  
});
```